# Register react-bootstrap-typeahead with react hook form Controller

Tags: reactjs, forms, controller, onchange, typeahead

The typeahead is to search from a list of job titles. It seems to be working but the selected value is not returned. How do I get the job title selected?

```
<Controller as={AsyncTypeahead} name="job"
  control={control}
  options={options}
  placeholder="Search for a job with either job code or description..."
  id="titleTypeahead"
  labelKey={option => `${option.detail}`}
  minLength={2}
  onSearch={async (e) => {
    getTitleByCriteria({ variables: { criteria: e.toUpperCase() } });
  }}
  onChange={(e) => {
    props.getSelectedJob(e[0]);
  }}
  renderMenuItemChildren={renderMenuItemChildren}
/>
```